# Is the order of multiple __exit__ calls in a with-block always deterministic?

Tags: python, contextmanager

Given the following `ContextManager` classes, here is the order of `__exit__` calls in the following example - reverse order of declaration.

Interestingly, `__exit__` can be called multiple times. Is this deterministic in all versions of Python from 2.7? If not, from **which version** is this order reliably deterministic?

```
a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

with a, b, c, a, a:
    print("Start")
```

---

##### Test harness

```
from typing import ContextManager

class A(ContextManager):
    def __exit__(self, __exc_type, __exc_value, __traceback):
        print("A exit")

class B(ContextManager):
    def __exit__(self, __exc_type, __exc_value, __traceback):
        print("B exit")

class C(ContextManager):
    def __exit__(self, __exc_type, __exc_value, __traceback):
        print("C exit")

a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

with a, b, c, a, a:
    print("Start")
```

Python 3.7+ output:

```
Start
A exit
A exit
C exit
B exit
A exit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple context managers on the same `with` line are handled as if they are nested. So this:

```
with a, b, c:
    stuff()
```

is equivalent to this:

```
with a:
    with b:
        with c:
            stuff()
```

That is, the `__enter__` methods are called left to right, and when the block ends, the `__exit__` methods are called right to left.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this deterministic in all versions of Python from 2.7?

Yes, the order is well defined [since 2.7 at least](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes):

> ```
> with A() as a, B() as b:
>    ... suite of statements ...
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> with A() as a:
>    with B() as b:
>        ... suite of statements ...
> ```

The order you got (reading from the bottom)

```
Start
A exit
A exit
C exit
B exit
A exit
```

is indeed A, B, C, A, A, as expected.

Comment: "it is not multiple times per object." Actually, it is. There is only 1 ``a=A()`` in the OP's example, and it is exited three times. Whether that is sensible or not is up to the context manager, not Python.